# Expand variable with semicolons in VS project file for PreprocessorDefinitions

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, msbuild

I'm using [this idea](/a/29879657/1566525) to inject preprocessor definitions from a command line build script using a global named `$(DefineConstants)`.

**vcxproj file snippet:**

```
  <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <DefineConstants></DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>
...
  <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'">
    <ClCompile>
      <PreprocessorDefinitions>$(DefineConstants);WIN32;_WINDOWS;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
```

My script launches `msbuild` with the following (abridged) command line:

```
msbuild.exe Solution.sln /p:DefineConstants=FOO%3BBAR
```

where `FOO%3BBAR` is dynamic and comes from any number of user-supplied values. (Using `%3B` as a separator comes from [this thread](/a/29096797/1566525) since using a raw `;` character results in an error.)

But the compiler (`cl`) command line shows that the entire value of `$(DefineConstants)` is getting placed into a single `/D` switch instead of getting split into multiple.

```
ClCompile:
  CL.exe ... /D "FOO;BAR" /D WIN32 /D _WINDOWS
```

It's as if the semicolons inside the variable aren't expanded. Is there any way to make it produce `/D FOO /D BAR`?

Summary of things I've tried so far:

| `msbuild` command line | results in `cl` command line | comment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `/p:DefineConstants=FOO%3BBAR` | `/D "FOO;BAR"` | wrong: not split into multiple `/D` |
| `/p:DefineConstants="FOO;BAR"` | `/D "\"FOO" /D "BAR\""` | wrong: split, but includes `\"` |
| `/p:DefineConstants=FOO;BAR` | n/a | error: [property not valid](/questions/24830088/command-line-msbuild-with-multiple-defineconstants) |

Comment: Hi, any update of this issue, does Jonathan's answer answer your question? :)

Answer (score 1):

I tested with the following small test file:

```xml
<Project>
  <Target Name="TestProp">
    <Message Text="$(DefineConstants)" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Example commands and outputs:

|  | MSBuild Command | Output | Comment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | `msbuild test.proj /p:DefineConstants=FOO;BAR` |  | MSB1006 error |
| 2 | `msbuild test.proj /p:DefineConstants=FOO;DefineConstants=BAR` | BAR |  |
| 3 | `msbuild test.proj /p:DefineConstants=FOO,DefineConstants=BAR` | BAR |  |
| 4 | `msbuild test.proj /p:DefineConstants="FOO;BAR"` | FOO;BAR |  |
| 5 | `msbuild test.proj /p:"DefineConstants=FOO;BAR"` | FOO;BAR |  |
| 6 | `msbuild test.proj /p:DefineConstants=FOO%3BBAR` | FOO;BAR |  |

The [`/property` switch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-command-line-reference?view=vs-2022#switches) (short version `/p`) to MSBuild defines an [MSBuild Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-properties?view=vs-2022). The `/property` switch accepts one or more name/value pairs delimited by semicolon or comma.

Example 1 is an error because the switch is expecting a name/value pair after the semicolon. `BAR` is either a name without a value or a value without a name.

The same name can appear multiple times. MSBuild just redefines the property. Essentially the last value is used. This is what is happening in examples 2 and 3.

Examples 4 and 5 use quotes to show the semicolon is part of one name/value pair.

Example 6 is hex encoding the semicolon.

Note that in examples 4, 5, and 6 the value of the `DefineConstants` property doesn't include quotes.

When `$(DefineConstants)` is replaced in `PreprocessorDefinitions` it should be :

```xml
      <PreprocessorDefinitions>FOO;BAR;WIN32;_WINDOWS;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
```

But somewhere in your project, quotes are being added. Is there code that you haven't shown, that is modifying the `DefineConstants` property?